# Webbing or cocooning movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely remember a movie where people and autos in a town get cocooned/covered in silk in '80s/'90s.

Was there such a movie?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is slightly earlier (1977) but in [Kingdom of the Spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_the_Spiders) there are several shots of people and other items cocooned in spider silk.  In fact

> at the end when 'Rack' (William Shatner) looks outside the house the entire landscape is covered in spider webs. "To their surprise, the radio broadcast does not mention the attack; the outside world is oblivious to what happened. Hansen pries off the boards from one of the lodge's windows, and discovers the building, along with the entire town of Camp Verde, encased in spider silk cocoons."

[image: Cocooning]

Answer (score 5):

[Could it be Eight-legged Freaks (2002)?](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0271367/)
[image: Eight-Legged Freaks!]

Commonalities:
Town gets plagued by mutant spiders. Cocooning /silk-covering of pretty much everything in the town ensues.

Comment: OP says the film is '80s or '90s, so a 2002 film wouldn't fall in that timeframe.

Comment: It was not entirely clear to which remembered element was vague and to what extent; the commonalities of film content match very well, and it’s equally closer to 90s age as Kingdom of Spiders is to 80s.

Comment: @SillybutTrue, maybe so, but it's far more likely that a 1977 film was watched in the 80s or 90s than a 2002 film was.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Maybe so, but it’s far more likely that what may have been thought to be a late 90s film would be a 2002 film than a 1977 film is.

Comment: @SillyButTrue but they didn't say late 90's.  They said 80's/90's.  And while they didn't specify whether they meant "watched" or "released", they're far more likely to be remembering a watch date than a release date (which they might not have even known).  I'm not criticizing your answer - memories are terrible and it's definitely plausible. I just don't think you should characterize it as "equally close" as a 1977 film - it might be technically the same distance but it's not equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this isn't an entirely off topic answer here, but your remembered movie may actually have been the news.

[Wagga Wagga, Australia, 2012](https://www.dw.com/en/our-beautiful-planet-blanketing-a-town-in-spider-silk/a-45494231)

[Rowlett, Texas, USA, 2015](https://citybugs.tamu.edu/2015/07/31/spider-city-in-rowlett/)

[Aitoliko, Greece, 2018](https://www.cnn.com/2018/09/20/europe/spider-webs-greek-town-trnd/index.html)

[Gippsland, Australia, 2021](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-57492960)

These are just a sample of the top search results, I'm sure this was happening in the 80s and 90s, too.

No people cocooned or harmed, as far as I know, but occasionally weather conditions are just right and spiders will absolutely blanket a large area.

Comment: I've never seen a story id question end up not being a story, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Fitting neatly between *Kingdom of the Spiders* and *Eight-Legged Freaks*, as well right in the middle of the timeframe, is [*Arachnophobia* (1990)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099052/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0). I can’t find any screenshots showing a person, car, or town being cocooned in webbing in the film, but my recollection is that by the end of the film the webs were pretty well everywhere.

Comment: Thanks guys I think it was Kingdom of the Spiders

Answer (score 0):

Not a Movie but the episode fits the description.

The X-Files Season 1 Episode 20 - Darkness Falls  (1994)
Description from imdb.com

> A group of loggers working in a remote forest unearths thousands of deadly insectlike creatures that paralyze and cocoon their victims. Scully, Mulder and a few others end up trapped there.

Couldn't find a good picture to link.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your quote says "remote forest;" is there a town involved that gets webbed too?

Comment: It's been a few years since I've seen the episode. I think there was a small village, but that didn't get webbed. The main focus is a small cabin and a few cars.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct is [Cocoon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088933/) (1985) about a group of seniors affected by swimming with, well, Cocoons...